# How to remove from DateTime variable hours, minutes, seconds and other parts in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

How to remove from DateTime variable hours, minutes, seconds and other parts in SSIS

If I have DateTime like `21 jul 2019 8:30:05`, and I want have it as `21 jul 2019 00:00:00` and still as DateTime not string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using a derived column:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(DT_DBDATE)@[User::DateTimeVariable]
```

Casting to `DT_DBDATE` will remove the time part, then recasting to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` will re-add a time part but with `12:00 AM` value = `00:00:00`

*Example:*

[image]

Comment: It works, I tried it before, but did not realized that I need to case to DBTimeSTAMP to make it work.